# Build OpenSSL with only Diffie-Hellman for iOS

Tags: ios, openssl

I have built OpenSSL for iOS using [this](https://github.com/x2on/OpenSSL-for-iPhone) github repository. Unfortunately built library is 44 MB in size. This is far to much.

I need to use OpenSSL only for Diffie-Hellman key exchange implementation. I think size of library will be significant reduced if I would extract only Diffie-Hellman part from it. Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how I can do it?

Comment: Check CopcoaPods [OpenSSL](https://cocoapods.org/?q=OpenSSL)

Comment: @zaph yes, I have seen this but it is only concept. I'm looking for working implementation.

Comment: Not a solution for right now but do file a [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com), I have (21468609), the more the better.

Comment: @Zaph - what does CocoaPods' OpenSSL have to do with the question? Does it provide an OpenSSL that only offers Diffie-Hellman? (Or perhaps some other reduced size build?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can anyone tell me if this is possible and how I can do it?

Well, I've never seen OpenSSL configured in this manner, so I'm not sure how close to the goal you can get. But what you are looking for is the various `no-xxx` options for `Configure`. I'm also not aware of a comprehensive list of them.

To add an additional wrinkle, you only need `libcrypto` (which provides the cryptography, like Diffie-Hellman), and not `libssl` (which provieds the higher level SSL/TLS functions).

---

Another approach is to worry less about the on-disk size of the archive or library, and focus of stripping the unneeded portions when the library is linked to a program. To do so, perform the following:

```
CFLAGS += -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections
LDFLAGS += -Wl,-dead_strip
```

That will allow the linker to remove any code or data not used in the final binary. Since you are only using Diffie-Hellman (and related functions, like Big Integers), that's the only thing that should be present.

(On Linux, you would use `LDFLAGS += -Wl,--gc-sections`).

---

OpenSSL does not always honor your `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`. If that's the case, you might need to add a special rule for `Configure` when building OpenSSL for iOS. To do that, see the discussion of RPATH's at [Compilation and Installation | Using RPATHs](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation#Using_RPATHs) on the OpenSSL wiki.