# Customize OpenSSL library to compatible with small embedded device

Tags: c, openssl, embedded

Here is my situation:

1. I want to implement BigNumber `BN_mod_exp` function on my embedded device which has no operating system running on.
2. OpenSSL provides me with this function, however I just want its `BN_mod_exp` function. So I want take out this specific function and its relevant functions as well as relevant structures.

Here is problem:

1. OpenSSL library is too complex that I cannot take functions simply out, even though what I need is just `BN_mod_exp`.
2. I plan implement that on an embedded device, which provides basic assembly (no OS) for OpenSSL. But normally, OpenSSL will take advantage of interfaces provided by operating system.

So in order to implement efficient big number `BN_mod_exp` operation on my embedded device, how could I do to customize OpenSSL library to make it work ?

Comment: Have you considered rolling your own?

Comment: I implemented my own. Question is my code ran too slow to apply to RSA encryption/decryption. While this library provides good efficiency.

Comment: The function you referenced likely needs `BN_add`, `BN_sub`, `BN_mul`, `BN_div`, and `BN_mod` to do its work.  For RSA, you'll also need `BN_mod_inverse` to generate the private key.

Comment: Right. when I try to take them out, they require many other functions and structures. Do you mean that I can go ahead to take all of them out and try to compile ??

Comment: Yes, try grabbing all of those functions.  If it complains about something missing, grab that too.

Comment: @JayZz - be very careful about rolling your own. There are so many ways to go wrong its hard to enumerate them all. Here's a quick example: did you implement a [Montgomery Ladder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_modular_multiplication) to resist timing and analysis attacks? Also, when performance is the metric, its hard to beat an implementation by Andy Polyakov. Andy is part of the OpenSSL project and he's the yardstick I measure performance by.

Comment: Here's a related question: [Build OpenSSL with only Diffie-Hellman for iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32897777). The answer is mostly the same: compile with `-ffunction-sections -fdata-sections` and link with `-Wl,--gc-sections`. Allow the linker to do its job, and help it when needed.